# Why is my react app not fetching my api data files?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am still learning MERN stack and I was able to deploy applications twice. I am trying to deploy this MERN stack application but I have not been able to do that for hours.

I placed my reactjs build files in my api folder in a folder called build. This is my folder structure:
[image]

In my app.js, I served my static files:

```
//routes
app.use("/api/v1/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/api/v1/users",userRoute);
app.use("/api/v1/posts",postRoute);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/build')))

 app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/build', 'index.html'));
})
app.use(checkDB);

module.exports = app;
```

In my reactjs, I called my one of my api endpoints like this:

```
const URL = 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1'

export default function Home() {
   useEffect( () => {
    dispatch({ type: "ISLOADING_START" });
    const fetchPosts = async ()=>{
    
   const res = await axios.get(URL+"/posts"+search)
    setPosts(res.data)
    dispatch({ type: "ISLOADING_END" });
    }
    fetchPosts()
     
}, [search])
  }
```

When I start my backend on port 5000, I tried to access my application but I can only get the header section of the html.
[image]

The body remains empty and the page loads forever. It seems not able to fetch the api data. I sincerely dont know. I have watched videos on youtube and I can't seem to find solution.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a dedicated route for index.html. That is messing up with your static folder.

Just use serve static and it will handle serving index.html with everything listed in the folder.

This should be enough for you

```js
app.use("/api/v1/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/api/v1/users", userRoute);
app.use("/api/v1/posts", postRoute);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/build')));

app.use(checkDB);

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Alright, man, I will try this and get back here to inform you. Thanks for this

Comment: thank you for trying to help but it didnt work. Still the same thing.

Comment: show your network tab and the error you have in the console

Comment: Console.log shows something like this: GET http://localhost:5000/reactblogapp/static/js/main.fc324a03.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. Nothing else. The network tap has main.fc324a03.js with the error message of failed to load response data. No data found with resource with given identifier

Comment: What is `reactblogapp`? where it came from. You don't have it in your code. Try without it

Comment: I sincerely didnt add that. I tried access my app using localhost:5000 which is the backend port

Comment: Judging from your observation, I was able to trace where the reactblogapp is located in my code. I added it in my reactjs package.json file when I was using git-pages to host my react app months ago. I have removed it is working now. And worked with these line of codes: app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
})
Thank you so much, you called my attention to issue that helped me.